# Fast scrolling speed when selecting part of question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, scrolling

Sometimes, when I am asking a question on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, I want to select part of my question or code I am writing in the 'Body' block, the frame where you type your question.

But the scrolling goes so fast that I end up selecting the whole thing instead of just the part that I want. Making the frame bigger helps a bit, but is there a way to slow down the scrolling?

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange :) Did you consider using keyboard for fine grained text selection?

Comment: @NimeshNeema That could be a good solution.

Comment: You can drag the bottom edge of the text field lower to make it bigger. Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent setting/configuration or programming for the *textarea* control (text input editor where you type your question/answer) to control the scroll speed.

The scroll speed you observe is derived from the OS scroll speed setting configured in your Operating System and the choice of hardware (trackpad/mouse).

To have a fine grained control over text selection, consider using keyboard. The cursor movement can be performed with the arrow keys (<kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>)which are the same across all major OS (macOS, Windows, Linux). Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys along with cursor keys lets you select the text.

Depending on your OS, you can additionally use <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd> key to speed up text selection (for e.g. by selecting, character, word or line at a time).